# Use passed parameter as a value in query string in django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use a passed parameter as a value in a django query string?

So, let's pretend I want to search for specific terms (in `term_list`) in different fields, like `username`, `display_name` or `name`.

Instead of doing this multiple times:

```
q1_username = Q(username__icontains=term_list[0])
q1_email = Q(email__icontains=term_list[0])

q2_username = Q(display_name__icontains=term_list[0])
q2_email = Q(e_mail__icontains=term_list[0])

q3_username = Q(name__icontains=term_list[0])
q3_email = Q(emailaddress__icontains=term_list[0])
```

I want to be able to do this in a more generic way for different cases:

```
q1_username = "display_name"
q1_email = "emailaddress"
q1 = build_query(term_list, q1_username, q1_email)

def build_query(term_list, passed_username, passed_email):
    q_username = Q(insert_passed_username_here__icontains=term_list[0])
    q_email = Q(insert_passed_email_here__icontains=term_list[0])
    # ...
    return query
```

If I try it like that, I get, not surprisingly, the following error message: `Cannot resolve keyword 'insert_passed_username_here' into field.`

How can I use the `passed_username` and `passed_email` to replace the `insert_passed_username_here` and `insert_passed_email_here` in the function?

EDIT:
According to the answer from @Tsang-Yi Shen I updated my function but I'm still getting errors. So let's edit my question like this, to make my case more clear:

I have several usernames and emails in different databases like this:

```
"""query 1"""
q1_username = Q(username__icontains=term_list[0])
q1_email = Q(email__icontains=term_list[0])

special_q1 = q1_username | q1_email
for term in term_list[1:]:
    special_q1.add((Q(username__icontains=term) | Q(email__icontains=term)), special_q1.connector)

"""query 2"""
q2_username = Q(name__icontains=term_list[0])
q2_email = Q(email__icontains=term_list[0])

special_q2 = crimenetwork_username | crimenetwork_email
for term in term_list[1:]:
    special_q2.add((Q(name__icontains=term) | Q(email__icontains=term)), special_q2.connector)
```

After building this, I then filter the results like this:

```
context = {}
context["q1_user_list"] = Users1.objects.using("db1").filter(special_q1)
context["q2_user_list"] = Users2.objects.using("db2").filter(special_q2)
```

Problem: I have about 30 queries like this and want to be able to this in a more generic way.

How can I achieve this with like dictionary unpacking?

Answer (score 3):

I often create a dictionary first then unpack it such as:

```
def build_query(term_list, passed_username, passed_email):
    q_username_dict = {passed_username + '__icontains': term_list[0]}
    q_username = Q(**q_username_dict)
    q_email_dict = {passed_email + '__icontains': term_list[0]}
    q_email = Q(**q_email_dict)
```

Though I'm still finding a  more graceful solution to this.

#### Edit:

Since you are finally put all your `Q`s into a `filter()`, I suggest to create a list of `Q` objects:

```
def make_query(passed_username, passed_email, term_list):
     return [
         (Q(**{passed_username + '__icontains': term}) |
          Q(**{passed_email + '__icontains': term})
         for term in term_list
     ]
```

Then unpack the list:

```
q_list = make_query('username', 'email', ['term01', 'term02'])
context["q1_user_list"] = Users1.objects.using("db1").filter(*q_list)
```

Also I eliminate the use of `.add()` and `.connector` since it should be equivalent to an `AND` operation between `Q`s. Hope that I did not misunderstand your meaning

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice concept. However, I'm getting a `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Q' and 'str'` error.

Comment: So your `passed_username` is also a `Q` object?

Comment: No, it's just a string, like this: `username = "display_name"`

Comment: I have updated my answer for your case. Hope that is your meaning